# Can the orignial exception type be found in a rethrown generic exception?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, exception

I'm trying to catch a user defined permission exception - i.e. a user does something their level of system access won't allow, permission exception is thrown. My problem is, the exception is caught and then rethrown as a genertic `System.Exception`.

Is there any way I can deduce the original exception type, without resorting to string comparisons, like `if ex.ToString.Contains("Permission denied") Then ...`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the InnerException property of the base Exception class, and loop until null

```
        try
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            while (e.InnerException != null)
                e = e.InnerException;

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: your sample will throw a NullReferenceException if there is at least one InnerException

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Try


Catch e as Exception
    While e IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not TypeOf(e) is PermissionException
       e = e.InnerException;
    End While

    ' Rethrow if we can't handle it
    If e Is Nothing Then Throw 

    ' do whatever needs to be done when PermissionException is thrown

End Try
```

Comment: Hmmm... this looks good. I modified the code a bit, using WHILE E ISNOT NOTHING, and then an if TypeOf(e) is PermissionException (someone might want to handle other exceptions as well in the future), but the code won't pick up on TypeOf(e) Is PermissionException. It can't seem to determine the type.